# org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file with birt 2.3.2 and firefox 15

Tags: birt

We are using Birt 2.3.2. 
We tried to open our report in Firefox 15.0.1, we are getting exception "org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file" without a stack trace.

We tried to debug it and found that firefox is sending wrong content-type. When I modify the header of request using Tamper Data plugin it worked.

The request which was sent is

```
POST <<URL>> 
Request Headers:
Host[<<MYHOST>>]
User-Agent[Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0.1]
Accept[text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8]
Accept-Language[en-us,en;q=0.5]
Accept-Encoding[gzip, deflate]
Connection[keep-alive]
Content-Length[1702]
Content-Type[application/x-www-form-urlencoded]
Referer[<<URL>>]
request-type[SOAP]
SOAPAction[""]
X-Prototype-Version[1.4.0]
X-Requested-With[XMLHttpRequest]
Cookie[JSESSIONID=A5E874082FE87F814F32B103EE864EBF.]
Pragma[no-cache]
Cache-Control[no-cache]
Post Data:
POST_DATA[<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><<SOAPBODY>></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>]
Response Headers:
Server[Apache-Coyote/1.1]
X-Powered-By[Servlet 2.5; JBoss-5.0/JBossWeb-2.1]
Content-Type[text/xml;charset=utf-8]
Transfer-Encoding[chunked]
Date[Fri, 28 Sep 2012 00:05:39 GMT]
Connection[close]
```

When we modify Content-Type to text/xml; charset=UTF-8, it worked

It also work with chrome and IE and sometime it works for FF but after we restart FF again problem appears.

Is there a way to fix it?

```
On server we are getting following exception

jvm 1    | java.io.CharConversionException: isHexDigit
jvm 1    |      at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.convert(UDecoder.java:88)
jvm 1    |      at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.convert(UDecoder.java:49)
jvm 1    |      at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters.urlDecode(Parameters.java:429)
jvm 1    |      at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters.processParameters(Parameters.java:412)
jvm 1    |      at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters.processParameters(Parameters.java:363)
jvm 1    |      at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParameters(Request.java:2562)
jvm 1    |      at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParameterNames(Request.java:1102)
jvm 1    |      at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParameterMap(Request.java:1082)
jvm 1    |      at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParameterMap(RequestFacade.java:414)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.doPost(BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.java:196)
jvm 1    |      at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
jvm 1    |      at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
jvm 1    |      at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.service(BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.java:122)
jvm 1    |      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
jvm 1    |      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the engine from a servlet, make sure you set the content type in the response:

response.setContentType("text/html");

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a known bug as [listed on Eclipse bug list](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=310512#c6).

Look at comment #6:

> The workaround is to comment out lines 668 and 669 of webcontent/birt/ajax/lib/prototype.js
>
> Before commenting out the lines, Chrome will send Content-type as "application/x-www-form-urlencoded, text/xml; charset=UTF-8", which causes the exception.
>
> After commenting out the lines, Chrome will send Content-type as "text/xml; charset=UTF-8", like other well-behaved browsers :)
>
> The prototype.js shipped with BIRT report seems rather old though, as that part of the code has been modified in version 1.5.0_rc0 more than 4 years ago